# Using Messenger with an enumerated token doesn't seem to work as expected

Tags: mvvm-light

Please help.. I'm trying to use the messenger class for cross view comms, specifically I want to route all errors (exceptions) through to the main view where I can pop up a nice UI with the error and some suggestions what to do.

I have a static class in a shared project with all my apps message types as an enumeration. (reduced down to one in the example below)

```
public static class AppMessages
{
    enum MessageTypes
    {
        RaiseError
    }
    public static class RaiseErrorMessage
    {
        public static void Send(Exception ex)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Send(ex, MessageTypes.RaiseError);
        }

        public static void Register(object recipient, Action<Exception> action)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Register(recipient, MessageTypes.RaiseError, action);
        }
    }
}
```

To register I call into a static method on a static class within the same shared project, for example..

```
AppMesssages.RaiseErrorMessage.Register(this,OnRaiseErrorMessage);
```

To send I use ...

```
AppMessages.RaiseErrorMessage.Send(e);
```

Now the issue I have is unless I change those tokens to the same value say "1" I don't recieve the message, but I can't see for the life of me why the use of the enum doesn't work?

So to be clear I only get the message if I use...

```
    public static class RaiseErrorMessage
    {
        public static void Send(Exception ex)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Send(ex, 1);
        }

        public static void Register(object recipient, Action<Exception> action)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Register(recipient, 1, action);
        }
    }
```

I just keep staring at the code and now I have brain freeze, tell me what I doing wrong. Many Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

@user1014297, I have implemented a similar solution using an Enum and it works.  It might be a threading issue and/or that the instance that is used for registering the receiver run out of scope.

My solution uses MEF as well as MVVM Light, I send exceptions from various MEF modules to the MEF start-up application.  All exception are shown using single UI.  I have simplified the code  below for illustration purposes

Registration:

```
  public static bool _handleErrorUIRegistered;

    private static void _registerExceptionHandlerUI(object instance)
    {
        if (_handleErrorUIRegistered) return;
        _handleErrorUIRegistered = true;
        Messenger.Default.Register<Exception>(
            instance,
            Sym.SL.Shared.Enums.Dialogs.Error,
            ex =>
            {
                // Do something
                GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Threading.DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Showing the error: + \r\n\r\n" + ex.Message);
                });
            });
    }
```

Sending Message:

```
Messenger.Default.Send<Exception>(new Exception("Test Error"), Sym.SL.Shared.Enums.Dialogs.Error);
```